# Is this an external cannon on an F-16?

Tags: military

What is the black pod starboard of the front landing gear on this F-16-I? At first I thought that it was a laser finder, but upon closer inspection it seems to resemble some type of short cannon. What might it be?

[image: F-16]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you seem to have found is the **Litening Targeting Pod**.

> Northrop Grumman's widely fielded LITENING system is a combat proven,
>   self-contained, multi-sensor targeting and surveillance system.
>   LITENING enables aircrews to detect, acquire, auto-track and identify
>   targets at extremely long ranges for weapon delivery or nontraditional
>   intelligence, surveillance and reconnaissance missions. [Source](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/litening/Pages/default.aspx)

[pod http://media.defenceindustrydaily.com/images/ELEC_LITENING-AT_on_F-16C_lg.jpg](http://media.defenceindustrydaily.com/images/ELEC_LITENING-AT_on_F-16C_lg.jpg)

The F16 does have a cannon as well, but it's located on the port side under and aft of the canopy: 
[image: cannon]

Comment: Thank you! Might I ask how you found that? My google-fu must need some improving.

Comment: @i googled 'f16 weapons', came up with [this](http://2g.pantip.com/cafe/wahkor/topic/X13050424/X13050424-4.jpg) image and was able to make out something about a pod that looked similar :) happy to help

Comment: Mind that an external gun pod for the F-16 was created when it was planned to replace the A-10 with the F-16. It was the GAU-13 and used a scaled down version of the A-10s GAU-8 gun. It was however never produced in numbers and never entered operational service because of its poor accuracy.

Comment: At the start of Desert Storm the USAF did in fact deploy a squadron of 'A-16s' to perform CAS and ground attack using a podded GAU-8.   Unfortunately, the only place on an F-16 (of that era anyway) to load an ECM pod is the centerline station, which is also the only place the GAU-8 can be loaded.  

It only took a couple of near miss SAM engagements before the 'A-16' was converted back into a proper F-16.